# Given the same remote LDAP server, why does Directory Utility work on one machine but not on the other?

Tags: macos, ldap, directory-utility

I have an LDAP server (OpenLDAP) running under Ubuntu 20.04 that I use for user authentication in my network, which consists of Linux servers and MacOS 11 clients. On my desktop, which runs MacOS 11.1, I can use `Directory Utility` to access the LDAP database without any problems.

I have a MacMini that I upgraded last week to MacOS 11.2. When I try to use `Directory Utility` on that machine, I get the error "Connection failed to the directory server (2100)" as soon as I select the LDAP server (as "/LDAPv3/*servername*") and before any prompt for username and password.

There is a known problem with logging in to remote LDAP servers that can be resolved by executing the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/*
do
  LDAP_SERVER=`/usr/bin/basename $f ".plist"`
  echo $LDAP_SERVER

  SASL_MECHANISMS="`/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -h $LDAP_SERVER -b '' -s base -LLL "(objectclass=*)" supportedSASLMechanisms | awk '{if($2 != "") printf "%s ",$2}'`"
  echo "  $SASL_MECHANISMS"

  /usr/bin/odutil set configuration /LDAPv3/$LDAP_SERVER  module ldap option "Denied SASL Methods" $SASL_MECHANISMS

done
```

I have executed this on both the desktop and the MacMini. So it seems that I have a different problem.

I looked at the log file of the LDAP server to see what happened when I selected `/LDAPv3/servername` and got the following:

```
Feb  7 01:42:17 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1266 fd=16 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.1.32:54621 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Feb  7 01:42:17 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1266 fd=16 closed (connection lost)

Feb  7 01:42:28 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1267 fd=16 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.2.127:65230 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Feb  7 01:42:28 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1267 fd=16 closed (connection lost)
Feb  7 01:42:28 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1268 fd=16 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.2.127:65231 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Feb  7 01:42:28 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1268 op=0 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
Feb  7 01:42:28 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1268 op=0 SRCH attr=supportedSASLMechanisms defaultNamingContext namingContexts schemaNamingContext saslRealm
Feb  7 01:42:28 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1268 op=0 ENTRY dn=""
Feb  7 01:42:28 s-tow-00 slapd[65708]: conn=1268 op=0 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
```

The MacMini (`conn=1266`, `IP=192.168.1.32`) returns immediately, whereas the desktop (`1267`, `1268`, `192.168.2.127`) proceeds to initiate a query.

I looked at the files in `/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3` on both machines to see if there was any difference there. Both contain entries for my LDAP servers (let's call them *server1* and *server2*). On the desktop, their permissions were 0644, whereas on the MacMini they were 0600. I cannot change the permissions with `chmod` (thank you, SIP), so I started `Directory Utility` with `sudo`, but the problem still persisted, so I conclude that it has nothing to do with permissions.

I then experimented with `dscl` in interactive mode. On the desktop I got the following:

```
> ls /LDAPv3/server1
Automount
AutomountMap
CertificateAuthorities
Groups
Mounts
OrganizationalUnit
People
Users
```

whereas all the MacMini could manage was

```
> ls /LDAPv3/server1
ls: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss knowing how to proceed. I thought about exporting the configuration from the desktop using `Directory Utility`'s "Write to Server" and then importing it on the MacMini, but I get "Operation is not supported by the directory node.", which I guess means that I have configured something incorrectly. I *can* "Save Template...", but the directory that I was told was intended for templates (`~/Library/Application Support/Directory Access/LDAPv3/Templates`) is stubbornly ignored on the MacMini.

Does anyone have any suggestions, please, as to how to proceed?

Steve

Comment: I have no answer to the differences of behaviour mentioned above. However, my MacMini is behaving strangely in other respects too, and I believe it is time to reinstall the operating system.

Comment: However, I have found out some background information that has enabled me to access LDAP correctly from the MacMini. I will present this in a sort of answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I learnt the following whilst fixing this problem. Perhaps it will help someone else in the future.

A MacOS LDAP client configured with `Directory Utility` stores the configuration data for LDAP servers that it knows about in `/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3` in plists named `<servername>.plist`. These files can be manipulated with `odutil` (see `man odutil`).

`Directory Utility` can be used to upload those plists from the local file system or from the LDAP server itself.

To access the plist from the local file system, copy it to `~/Library/Application Support/Directory Access/LDAPv3/Templates` and ensure that it is called `<anything>.plist` (i.e. it must have the filetype `.plist`). After that has been done, if you edit the server data in `Directory Utility` under the 'Search & Mappings' tab, in the drop-down labelled 'Access this LDAPv3 server using' you will see the text '<anything>' from the filename of the plist. If you select this, the settings from your plist will be applied to the client.

Similarly, it is possible to create an entry in the LDAP server itself that contains exactly the same text and use that instead. The following shows what I see in `ldapvi` when I look at the entry I created:

```
13 ou=macosxodconfig,<local RDN>,<LDAP base DN>
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: macosxodconfig
description:; <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">\
<plist version="1.0">\
<dict>\
    ...the rest of the plist comes here ...
</dict>\
</plist>
```

Note: everything from the ";" to the end of the definition is the contents of our plist - without the "\"s, which are an artefact of `ldapvi`. How you get the plist into your server is up to you: I use `Apache Directory Studio`. The only apparent restriction is that the entry must be an `organizationalUnit` called `ou=macosxodconfig`. After that has been done, if you edit the server data in `Directory Utility` under the 'Search & Mappings' tab, in the drop-down labelled 'Access this LDAPv3 server using' you will see the option 'From Server'. If you select this, you will be prompted for a search base (I suggest you choose '<local RDN>,<LDAP base DN>', replacing the stuff in angle brackets with something that makes sense on your context. The settings from your plist will then be applied to your client.

Just in case you forgot, you have to tell MacOS that your are using an LDAP server. You do this in `System Preferences` -> 'Users & Groups' -> 'Login Options': to the right you will see the label 'Network Account Server' with an 'Edit...' button next to it. Authenticate yourself by clicking on the lock at the bottom of the window, click on the 'Edit...' button and add your server(s) to the list here.

You may also need to go back to `Directory Utility` and add your LDAP server(s) to its 'Search Policy' (tab on the home window).

Steve